# No me conecta a la base de datos de mysql

Tags: java, sql, base-de-datos

me podrian ayudar en este caso...
aqui no se me quiere conectar a a base de datos ya le puse el scrip(conector), no creo que sea el usuario o la contraseña y ademas puse el host local, quiero que me digan el error o como podria conectarme mejor, porfavor...

aqui esta un poco del codigo(por cierto la base de datos se llama: CURSO):

```
    try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc: mysql://localhost:3306//CURSO", "java", "mysql");
    System.out.println("se conecto correctamente");
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Error al conectar la base de datos"); 
     }catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Error en la conecion"); 
    }
}
```

La clase es ConetionJDBC y tiene el metodo main si hay alguna informacion mas que deseen me lo hacen saber porfavor y gracias..

Comment: El error nos lo cuentas tú. Necesitas hacer que los catch impriman el mensaje de la excepción; de otra forma, no tenemos cómo ayudarte.

Comment: Cuál esle mensaje de error?

Comment: Tal y como comenta @Alfabravo, en ambos catch, en lugar de imprimir tus propios mensajes, imprime las excepciones -> e.printstacktrace();

Comment: Puedes usar [`printStackTrace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace()) en tu bloque `catch`, por ejemplo: `e.printStackTrace()`, de esta forma obtendrás exactamente la traza de error de tu intento de conexión. Cuando tengas eso, agrégalo a tu pregunta haciendo clic en [edit]. Saludos

Comment: gracias por el apoyo, el codigo me lanza una excepcion que dice "No suitable driver found for jdbc: mysql://LAPTOP-H6BK3JBC:3307/CURSO", no se si sea el driver el que tanga problemas o sino es la uri,

Comment: Ese mensaje, entiendo, te está diciendo que no tienes el driver adecuado para la conexión que estás intentando hacer.